# Can i display a smaller version of my website within facebook to avoid scrolling?

Tags: canvas, tabs, facebook-canvas

Im using a tab to display a version of my website within facebook.

Ive seen numerous how-to tutorials, on how to set up tabs, and how to resize canvas windows.
But.. is there a way to shrink my site that appears in a canvas.

Eg. at the moment my site displays on a canvas page and I have to scroll left and right as its to wide for the maximum 760px canvas size.

I really dont want to have to re-write my html/css.  Too many fixed width elements etc.

Is there any way I can get facebook to display a shrunk version of my site, to avoid the annoying scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

> I really dont want to have to re-write my html/css.

But you should – not your HTML, but your CSS.

Otherwise, if you’re just looking for a “lazy solution” here, you could only try to make the browser shrink the whole content of the html or body element, by using `zoom` or CSS3 tranforms on it – but the result will most likely look quite horrible.

Comment: I dont want my sight to change when viewed directly in a browser.  Is there a way to trigger a media query ONLY when the website is being viewed through a facebook tab/canvas?

Comment: Easiest way would be to add a GET parameter to the URL you use as your canvas URL – with that parameter set, add some style sheet rules (or just makes them applicable, by f.e. giving the HTML element an additional class); and without it, render the page in the “normal” way.